# Generating a 3D sine curve using python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a 3D sine curve in python. Does lumpy support it or is there another library I can use for it?

Generating a 2D curve is straightforward something like this --

```
x = numpy.linspace(0, 20, 0.1)
y = numpy.sin(x)
```

I now have x and y I can save to disk.

Now I want to do something similar but for a 3D sine curve over x, y and z axes. I am hoping someone might have done it before and help me.

EDIT: I have realized that for my use case I want a 2D curve in 3D space. So the other axes can be constant. So I am simply generating a 2D curve and adding a constant third parameter value to get the x,y,z values.

Comment: I'm not aware of a generalization of the sine function to more than one dimensional input - could you link to a definition of such a function? If there isn't one, then what exactly does a 3D sine curve look like? I assume `x` is independent, as above, and `y = sin(x)`. What is `z` then?

Comment: Tbh, I don't know myself. I am imagining a sine curve thrown randomly into a 3D space. The curve will then not be aligned on any one axis but be at a random orientation. It will have x, y and z values at any given point. I don't know how to represent it, and am hoping someone knows.

Comment: A sine curve randomly situated in 3d space can be represented as a sine multiplied by a 4d homogeneous rotation. 3d applications use such matrices. If you have a sampled signal of sine then multiply each point by this rotation-translation matrix.

Comment: this needs some clarification.  The example you gave is 1 dimensional (not two): y is a function of single variable x.  Do you want z to be a function of (x, y), or do you want a f_value = f(x,y,z)?

Comment: Do you want a curve in 3D, like this: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/lines3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-lines3d-py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
z = y*np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

c = x + y

ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c)
```

or maybe you want `z = x*np.sin(x)` or even `z = np.sin(y)`

Edit: maybe this is the best solution `z = np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2))` from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381950/3d-sine-cosine-formula-and-name)

Have a play and to find what you want. Pretty funky stuff and depends on exactly what output you are looking for.